# Blender crashes on start up

Tags: startup-file

I used blender back then and it was working fine. I was using it for weeks and I stopped using it since I got busy. After 3 months, I decided to open blender again but it didn't work. The weird thing is that when my friend copied the file that I have but it was working but mine isn't. I don't know what happened. Also, I had just recently upgraded my ram before I opened blender again.

Comment: Does Blender work with the default scene? Are you using the same version of Blender as your friend?

Comment: @rob as he said, he copied the same file, so both of them should have the same version! ;)